# Toggling IsVisible for an stacklayout inside scrollview does not update properly in Xamarin forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having lot of **stacklayout** views inside scrollview, and the stacklayouts visibility property set to "true" or "false" based on the option selected. Making stacklayout isvisible property to "true" is not working in **Xamarin Forms 1.4.0** and instead of showing the stacklayout view it's just showing empty space between the views.but it was working fine in **Xamarin Forms 1.3.3**. happening only in iOS, in android it is working as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am also having similar problem. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: No not yet. just switched back to Xamarin Forms 1.3

Comment: The issue has been fixed in **Xamarin Forms 1.4.2.6359**, tested and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in Forms see :

- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29086
- 

There is a workaround in the last thread, personnly I played with Opacity instead of Visibility, but it is not perfect since when setting Opacity = 0 the control desepears but the space used by this control is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all stacklayouts in one single stacklayout and put the main stacklayout in scrollview.

Comment: i am doing the same, i have a main stacklayout.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem also on IOS, our workaround until xamarin fixes this was extending the forms element (in our case a StackLayout) and on property changed, validate if the property is the IsVisible, and if this.IsVisible is true, we do a this.FadeTo.
Basically the code is like this:

```
if(e.PropertyName == StackLayout.IsVisibleProperty.PropertyName)
{
   if (this.Element.IsVisible)
   {
     this.Element.FadeTo(1f, 50);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread in Xamarin Repo](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13597) seems to be a good workaround.

Basically wrapping the ScrollView with a ContentView fixes the issue.

It worked for me!